# CImg save_jpeg() does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, jpeg, data-conversion, cimg

I have a problem with CImg. I want to convert .bmp file to .jpg one.

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
(...)
CImg<unsigned char> image("image.bmp");
image.save_jpeg("image.jpg", 60);
```

When I want to run this program, sometimes it return an error:
[CImag error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgCT8.png)

Sometimes it did not appear, but also did not create .jpg file.

I want to add, that another CImg functions works properly, like turning photo to a grayscale.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this code? Maybe it is another possible way to convert and save photo into .jpg file?

EDIT:
When I add

```
#define cimg_use_jpeg
```

before

```
#include <CImg.h>
```

I got a lot of errors regarding cimg.h [image: error]

Comment: Could you at least post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line **before** your `#include "CImg.h"`

```
#define cimg_use_jpeg 1
```

It tells `CImg` to use its own internal JPEG encoder/decoder rather than **ImageMagick** which you may not have installed.

For the sake of completeness, there is also:

```
#define cimg_use_tiff 1
#define cimg_use_png 1
```

Comment: I think that it should help. I cannot check it because now I try to install libjpeg. Without it it does not work. Do you know  fast and easy way to install libjpeg? I try to install with the instruction from https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg but this instrucion is too complicated. I try to install it for WIndows, VS2015